# user can send sms 8 times in a day

Tags: php, html

hello friends can any one help me i have site and i have alot of users for every user i make sms form and user web page ... my users send unlimited sms from my site through form this is html script of my sms form how i can set the limit of submitting form means i want 1 user send only 20 or 30 sms in 1 day .. or if any code or script like that i give web page to my user and after 5 days page are expaire so remaining days countdown system script and automatic redirect after 5 days web page

```
<p><label for="name">to</label><br />
   <input type="text" name="to" value="to" id="to" size="37" /></p>

<p><label for="email">from</label><br />
   <input type="text" name="from" value="from" id="from" size="37" /></p>

<p><label for="comment">message</label><br />
   <textarea name="message" rows="8" cols="35" id="message">message</textarea></p>

<p><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" /></p>`enter code here`
```

Comment: You should explain a bit more of your application. Are your users logging in to send SMS? Are you saving/logging sending messages per user?

Answer (score 2):

If you don't somehow authenticate your users, you cannot set any limits.

The best I can think of in that case is to somehow keep track of the IP addresses from which the SMS's are sent. Client IP is available in PHP inside [$_SERVER variable](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php). Even as such, authenticating users by IP address alone is very unreliable (proxies, dynamic IPs, etc.).

**My advice: Don't put this kind of form up in the wild.** It's a race against malicious users and spam bots, which you will eventually lose.

Comment: Throw in a local storage cookie

Comment: is this possible automatic disable the send button after pressing the 20 times

Comment: You have asked the same question on here many different times